# Jquery list filtering help required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I want to change a little function of list filtering instead of filtering **li**, i want to scan the multiple **ul** tags of the div which contains which contains same list items in it 
how is it possible with it

here is my js code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#s').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.domain_pricing_list>li').each(function(){
     var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();            
   });
  });
});
```

here is my html

```
<input placeholder="Search..." id="s" type="text" /> 
<div class="domain_pricing_list">
    <ul>
        <li><span>TLD</span>.com</li>
        <li><span>Duration</span>1 Year</li>
        <li><span>Registration</span>$10</li>
        <li><span>Renewal</span>$10.45</li>
        <li><span>Transfer</span>$10.33</li> 
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><span>TLD</span>.net</li>
        <li><span>Duration</span>1 Year</li>
        <li><span>Registration</span>$10</li>
        <li><span>Renewal</span>$10.45</li>
        <li><span>Transfer</span>$10.33</li> 
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><span>TLD</span>.org</li>
        <li><span>Duration</span>1 Year</li>
        <li><span>Registration</span>$10</li>
        <li><span>Renewal</span>$10.45</li>
        <li><span>Transfer</span>$10.33</li> 
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector is not correct. It should be:

```
$('.domain_pricing_list > ul >li')
```

`.domain_pricing_list > li` means "direct child of .domain_pricing_list" element. According to your HTML there are no such children. Direct descendants of `.domain_pricing_list` are `ul` tags.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/06kvcmqq/

Comment: I was doing the same thing but is there any way from which we can filer the <b>ul</b> tags by placing some kind of id or any thing else

Comment: You don't want to filter li's in all ul's? Just in some of them?

Comment: its ok but one little issue here when we write some in text filed we have to put TLD and secondly it removes all other list items of same group please try to write "TLD.com" in your jsfiddle you will notice it removes prcings and also i dont want to write tld in text field

Comment: Why do you have to enter `TLD`?